# Errors when deleting images in Laravel when no record found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-storage

I want to delete some user, and if that user have an avatar i want to remove the avatar either. so i do like this :

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        if ($user && $user->profile->avatar){
            Storage::delete($user->profile->avatar);
        }

        User::destroy($id);
        return back();
    }
```

but when i  do this it give me an error like this when user doesn't have any record in avatar tables:

```
"Trying to get property of non-object"
```

so what make me get this errors and how can i fix it. thanks.

Comment: `$user->profile` could be null ... trying to use null as an object, would give that error ... you have to check for nulls

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object" at which line number?

Comment: On If. I think it at user->profile since the user doesn't have avatar.

Comment: @lagbox yes I think so. I make if just to make sure I don't get that errors but still

Comment: because you aren't checking for `null` ... you are just skipping ahead  `$something->something->something->something->something` any one of those properties could return null and the whole thing will error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if user has profile, first.

```
if ($user && $user->profile && $user->profile->avatar){
    Storage::delete($user->profile->avatar);
}
```

Anyways, doing this at model level will make your controller a little bit cleaner. Example for attaching a listener through the model directly.

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function ($instance) {
            if ($instance->profile && $instance->profile->avatar) {
                \Storage::delete($instance->profile->avatar);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Work great. Thanks.